# Error in akka clustering

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka-remote-actor, akka-remoting

I am developing a service using Akka clustering but I am getting these warnings when my program is running. I have an 8 node Akka cluster. Can anyone help me in solving this errors :

> [WARN] [06/07/2018 15:08:51.923]
>   [ClusterSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-18]
>   [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@192.168.2.8:2552/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FClusterSystem%40192.168.2.7%3A2552-8]
>   Association with remote system
>   [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@192.168.2.7:2552] has failed, address is now
>   gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with
>   [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@192.168.2.7:2552]] Caused by: [No response
>   from remote for outbound association. Handshake timed out after [15000
>   ms].]
>
> [WARN] [06/07/2018 16:07:06.347]
>   [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-101]
>   [akka.remote.PhiAccrualFailureDetector@3895fa5b] heartbeat interval is
>   growing too large: 2839 millis

Answer (score 0):

You will get these kind of errors when your HostIP is not matching with the configured seed nodes.

Also check your akka.remote configuration

```
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = on
    netty.tcp {
      bind-hostname = 0.0.0.0
      bind-port = ${hostport}

      hostname = ${hostip}
      port = ${hostport}
    }
  }
```

The hostname should match with your HostIP.

Comment: My code is running fine for some time and after like some 1 hour it is giving this warning. If it is a hostname warning then the code should give it at the starting only.

Comment: If your hostname and seed nodes are matching then it should be something to do with your network. Please check your network between nodes.

Comment: All the machines are connected to a LAN network. There is no any network problem but I will check it again can you tell me how to check the network error?

Comment: when you get a connection error in the log, use telnet to check wether you are able to reach the other node. if telnet not working then its a network issue.

Comment: I check as you said and i found that I am able to do telnet to that actor when i am getting the warning as `No response from remote for outbound association. Handshake timed out after [15000 ms]`